# Javascript/Css navigation not showing on jquery document ready in ie only

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using Dynamic Drives ddsmoothmenu script to display our site's navigation.  To prevent the menu showing for an instant while the page loads, I've added a show() function on document ready.  This works great in all browsers except ie.  Can someone please have a look at http://www.idataresearch.com and let me know if anything jumps out.  Thank you.  P.S. I've taken over for a failed developer, so please excuse the mess.

Comment: There's an error at line 945 of a script in the home page (*allowReverse is not defined*). This could disable other scripts in that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid error which appears in 945 line, try to change your if condition:

from:

```
if ( allowReverse && !document.layers ) { ... }
```

to:

```
if ( typeof allowReverse == 'undefined' && allowReverse != false && !document.layers ) { ... }
```

And it can cause other function/script failure

Comment: Thanks but I'm still getting the same error with that allowreverse line when I try that.

Comment: Can you paste the error, and the action where variable is setting?

Comment: Actually, I got rid of the wrong line.  I fixed it using your suggestion.